# Creating links in Flex

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
private function google(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(event.result.loginsuccess.keyword[0]);
                subtitle.visible=true;
                Results.visible=true;
                Occur.visible=true;
                query.visible=true;
                subtitle.text = "Search results for " +  event.result.loginsuccess.keyword[0];
                Results.text = event.result.loginsuccess.name;
                Occur.text = event.result.loginsuccess.occur;
                query.text = "query executed in " + event.result.loginsuccess.queryTime[0] + " Seconds";
            }
<mx:Text id="Results" x="130.5" y="180" text="Text" width="461" visible="false" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="16"/>
```

I am getting a list of websites in this text field, but i need to make them clickable. How can i do it. I mean the list of websites is random, it may be three or four or many.

The Format i am getting from backend is PHP and getting the response here in Flex through XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use HTML text and you'll need to generate it yourself from whatever results you get back from the php.

```
[Bindable]
private var link : String = '<p>some text here <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925492/creating-links-in-flex">stackoverflow</a> blah blah blah</p><p>even more text here <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">bbc</a> blah blah blah</p>';
```

then in the text field,

```
<mx:Text htmlText="{link}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html

Peter